# How to store image pixel values into txt file from MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, text, load, pixel

I just want to know that how to store image pixel values of an image in a text file in MATLAB?

I wrote the following code

```
Data = load('matlab.mat');

DataField = fieldnames(Data);

dlmwrite('FileName.txt', Data.(DataField{1}));
```

but when we look into text file all the pixel values are stored separated by comma. I just want all the pixel values without comma.

Please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 1):

use the `'\t'` delimiter option in `dlmwrite`:

```
dlmwrite('FileName.txt', Data.(DataField{1}),'delimiter','\t');
```

or just insert space using `...,'delimiter',' ')`

Comment: Shouldn't a simple space be better than a tab character? The OP doesn't seem to want any particular character between his pixel values.